# Two window bars / frames

Tags: windows

today I logged into Ubuntu and got this double window frames.

Any way to fix this?

Thank you!

[image: Screenshot]

**Update 1:** It should look like this, every thing crapped in one bar:

[image]
[Source](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yf6nXFuAIXQ/XJ5QGdQK04I/AAAAAAAArKs/z3zNiggijz8piYLB1izIHnbE4rVEgYL0QCLcBGAs/s640/ubuntu1904%2Bconsumo%2Bde%2Bram.jpeg)

Update 2: A restart fixed it, I don't know why but works now.

Comment: The lower bar is the menu-bar. I don't know how it comes to the stylish look. You can disable and enable the menu-bar easily. Just right-click somewhere in the terminal and choose the desired option.

Comment: This just shows the menu bar below the second bar :(